# Angular 2 check next route OnDestroy

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to trigger action on any `NavigationEnd` router event, except when navigating between 
a) child routes; 
b) on one another specific route.

Here is a piece of my `app.routing.ts`:

```
// some other routes setup...

{ path: 'scrapers/:version', component: SingleScraperComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'statistics', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'statistics', component: ScraperStatisticComponent },
    { path: 'targets', component: ScraperTargetsComponent },
]},

// some other routes setup...
```

Here is my `Router` events subscription in `SingleScraperComponent`:

```
// some component code

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).takeWhile(() => this.isAlive).subscribe(
        (event: NavigationEnd) => {
            console.log(event);
            if (event.url.indexOf('site-preview') === -1) {
               this._site.resetQuery();
            }
        }
    );
}

// some component code
```

I could also use `OnDestroy`, but I need to know next route after `SingleScraperComponent` destruction.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I have used `routerState` snapshot to verify next route:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this._router.routerState.snapshot.url.indexOf('site-preview') > -1) {
        console.log('Hello, from needed route!');
    }
}
```

But if there is a more clear way I would appreciate to know.